# Haskell mulitline do statements for simple testing

Tags: haskell, equality

If I want to quickly evaluate a bunch of one line equality tests, how can I do this in Haskell? I don't want to have to install anything or do anything fancy.

At the moment I can run these statements one at a time, but how can I just do it in one where it executes them line by line?

Here is an example of what works:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7

tests2 = do
  a == 5
--  b == 6
--  c == 7
```

This returns

```
True
```

as b and c are commented out. However if I try to run all three, like this:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7

tests2 = do
  a == 5
  b == 6
  c == 7
```

Then I get an error. How can I get it to just return

```
True
True 
True
```

This is just a really simple issue I am trying to quickly solve, I know that this isn't the proper way of writing Haskell, and I can do fancy things to check, I am just looking for something super simple and quick.

Comment: You never `print` anything, this is what the function *returns*, and `do`. `do` is just syntactical sugar to bind expressions.

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty stupid of me. Answer is: 
`a = 5
b = 6
c = 7

tests2 = do
  print ( a == 5 )
  print ( b == 6 )
  print ( c == 7 )`

Comment: a simpler answer is `tests2 = [ a == 5, b == 6, c == 7 ]`.

Comment: "return" and "print out" are way different things. Apparently, ghci prints out the thing that was returned (if possible), but it is not how it works in normally compiled programs

Comment: @13sen1: For future reference, when you need to write Haskell code in a comment here, since you can’t use the syntactic sugar of indentation, you ought to use explicit curly braces `{}` (around `do`, `case`…`of`, `where`, and `let` blocks) and semicolons `;` (between definitions and `case` branches), so that your code is syntactically correct, and easier to read & copy, e.g.: `a, b, c :: Int; a = 5; b = 6; c = 7; tests2 :: IO (); tests2 = do { print (a == 5); print (b == 6); print (c == 7); };`. You can also use backticks (as in ``a `mod` b``) by surrounding code with double backticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `do` block does not *do* anything. It is syntactical sugar to bind items together. But for an expression `do x`, is just equivalent to `x`.

If you thus write:

```
tests2 = do
  a == 5
```

then this is equivalent to:

```
tests2 = a == 5
```

this is thus an expression that will return a `Bool`.

If you write multiple expressions under a `do`, it will try to bind these with [**`(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-), so:

```
tests2 = do
  a == 5
  b == 6
  c == 7
```

is equivalent to:

```
tests2 = (a == 5) >> (b == 6) >> (c == 7)
```

but a `Bool` does not take a type parameter, so that can not work.

If you want to *print* the result, you can use [**`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) :

```
tests2 :: IO ()
tests2 = do
    print (a == 5)
    print (b == 6)
    print (c == 7)
```

ow `tests2` has type `IO ()`.